# Self-hosted synchronisation server for GTG (Getting Things Gnome 0.3.1)

Tags: synchronization

I often use [GTG 0.3.1](http://gtgnome.net/2013/11/back-again-release-0-3-1/) in combination with the [Hamster Tracker](https://projecthamster.wordpress.com/) on my laptop. However, I cannot see any possibility to sync my task from my laptop to my workstation computer.

I have tried RTM but first it does not work properly (my tasks were deleted) and second I would prefer a self-hosted solution. I also tried to file sync the GTG localfile with Sparkleshare what is not a good solution.

I think GTG would call it a "backend" what I am searching. Is there a way to setup a self-hosted GTG backend or task synchronisation server for GTG clients?

(Please don't suggest Evernote, etc. I am looking for a self-hosted solution.)

moved from: 
https://productivity.stackexchange.com/questions/14567/self-hosted-synchronisation-server-for-gtg-getting-things-gnome-0-3-1